# Add class to column in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append `<div class = 'myclass'>td-value</div>` in second column of table. Output should be

```
 <td><div class = 'myclass'>-1.3%</div></td>
```

I don't want to use `.addclass( )` because I need to append nested divs in my real problem. I produced small example for the same. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gho7mpx1/)

Comment: The question is confusing, why not to introduce your real problem, currently the question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will give you a little bit of idea.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
  var CONTROL_INTERVAL2 = setInterval(function(){
  
    $('table tbody td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
      const value = $(this).text().substr(0,1);
      if ( value == '-') {
        $('table tbody td:nth-child(2)').replaceWith("<div class = 'myclass'>" + $(this).val +"</div>");
      }
      else {
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
      }
      
      clearInterval(CONTROL_INTERVAL2);
    });
    
  }, 2000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple task when you use [html(function)](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)

```js
$('table tbody td:nth-child(2)').html(function(i,curr){
     return $('<div class="myclass">').text(curr);
})
```

```css
.myclass{font-weight:900; color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>Class1</td>
  <td>-1.3%</td>
  <td>Science</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Class2</td>
  <td>+3.3%</td>
  <td>Maths</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```